# c#.net create menu with submenu

Tags: c#, .net, menu

[image]

how is it possible to create the standard menu as on the image the first line and when you select one from the menu from the first line to open on the same form on the bottom and also to be show what you have select as on the second image in which it show which one is selected. 
also on the second line it display all the forms that you have open and you have the ability to move among them
how this can be done or something to read?

Comment: What platform is this in? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: am using visual studio the windows form application.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean here. Can you give more information or an example we might be familiar with>?

Comment: it will be one menu with subcategories which you can select from them. if you select something from the menu then a form will appeared inside your application. also a new menu will appeared under the standard menu in which it be will write the name of the selection.if you select other from first menu then the previousform will be hide and on the second menu will be write and the second form menu.you can must also move between the two open form by selecting from the second menu

Comment: as vidual studio open form and has a support menu that display open forms and you can move between them which hide form1 and open form2 and vice versa

Comment: it's c# windows form application